netaddr remove `is_private` method from BaseIP class in new version
I was using netaddr version 0.10.1, and its BaseIP class has method is_private. We are using that method as if mynetwork.is_private(): # DO SOMETHING.
Now we upgrade netaddr package to 1.2.1. In this new upgrade, BaseIP has no method call is_private. even IPV4_PRIVATEISH and IPV6_PRIVATEISH was removed.
I want to check is there any other method available which we can use for is_private? I tried if mynetwork in IPV4_PRIVATE_USE: # DO SOMETHING but this doesn't cover all cases covered by is_private method in 0.10.1.
Let me know if there is pythonic way to implement this is_private logic again.

Did you read the doc string of the code you linked?

@KlausD. I read that, but they suggest to use 3 different methods like is_link_local, is_ipv4_private_use and is_ipv6_unique_local, do you think there is another way to use as single method?

The doc string gives you your answer, what is left to do is to accept it.
